# sed insert character at specific positions

Tags: sed, text-formatting

I have hundreds of `*.txt` files which have a common format.

I can insert a comma at a specific position in one file, how can I generalize the below code to apply this operation at several places for all `*.txt`files in the directory?

```
sed -i 's/^\(.\{4\}\)/\1,/' blank.txt
```

For example inserting commas at positions 4, 8, 22 etc.

Something like this perhaps?

```
for i in *.txt; do
   sed -i 's/^\(.\{4\}\)/\1,/' $i
done
```

Comment: Are the locations specific, or do you still need a regex to match appropriate bits?

Comment: If, for example, you need to place a comma after the fifth character, `sed s/^...../&,/ /path/to/file` will do it.

Comment: In addition to the other answers provided, your first command could be simplified from `s/^\(.\{4\}\)/\1,/` to `s/^.\{4\}/&,/` and still be usable as an `ex` command or within `vi`.  (Of course it could be further simplified to `s/./&,/4` for use in `sed`.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Start from the rightmost one:

```
sed -i 's/./&,/22;s/./&,/8;s/./&,/4' ./*.txt
```

Otherwise, the first substitution would affect the offset for the second. You can always account for it though:

```
sed -i 's/./&,/4;s/./&,/9;s/./&,/24' ./*.txt
```

Answer (score 15):

In a *general* way, you can just do:

```
sed 's/./&,/4' <in >out
```

That will append a comma on output to the 4th character of all input lines with at least that many characters.

And, if you'll take my advice, you should generally *not* use the `-i` switch to any `sed` which offers one.

Comment: Can you please explain your refrain from `-i`? Without it the process of changing a file is `mv file file.new;sed '...' < file.new > file;rm file.new` which is cumbersome and unsafe against multiple users. In place editing has the additional advantage that given a small enough file (under the system default buffer size, which is quite large for text files) the edit is atomic in respect to other users)

Comment: @Guss - you describe it very well - though thats not the only way. `-i` doesn't edit the file but replaces it. It is especially a problem for multi-user systems, because, counterintuitively, the file's permissions don't matter and only it's parent directory's permissions do. `-i` alters metadata - maybe even ownership. The `mv file.new file.old` command you detail is exactly what `sed` does, only it doesn't advertise that fact, nor does it respect such norms as `$TMPDIR` nor even `~` and just writes to the read file's parent directory while it works, before `mv` it over the read file at exit.

Comment: Yes, you are correct - I was confusing with another program. Though `sed -i` does retain some metadata, under (what I believe is) acceptable measures given specific conditions. For specific details, see this answer - http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/146054/4323 .

Answer (score 0):

When you mention 'at positions 4,8 and 22', sed means 'one after positions 3,7 and 21'. You want to insert and keep the existing text as is.

This?:

```
sed -i -r "s/^(.{3})/\1,/;s/^(.{7})/\1,/;s/^(.{21})/\1,/" $(dirname "$0")/blank.txt
```

> -i = --in-place aka change directly in the existing file, -r = regular expression, \1 = refers to the 'group' between parenthesis, $(dirname
> "$0") = to stay in the current dir

A similar sed-use when you want to e.g. set tabs instead of spaces at certain positions in a file with lines seperated by single spaces:

```
sed -i -r "s/^(.{10})./\1\t/;s/^(.{20})./\1\t/;s/^(.{30})./\1\t/" $(dirname "$0")/blank.txt
```

Substitutes the characters (in this case single spaces) at position 11, 21 and 31 by a tab. The spaces within the created columns stay untouched.

You can still get the impression that this doesn't align/display your columns well in your text-editor. The coded tabs aren't wrong, but often you need to adapt the tab-setting in the text-editor preferences. E.g. Geany -> Preferences -> Editor -> Indentation -> Tabs width 8 instead of 4.

(The latter somewhat aside your original question...)

Comment: (1) The question says ``s/^\(.\{4\}\)/\1,/``. The fact that you say `s/^(.{3})/\1,/` suggests that you’re misunderstanding the question. (2) Since the question already mentions `sed -i`, it seems unnecessary for you to explain what it does. (3) Why are you talking about tabs?