# Sed with inplace editing changes group ownership of file

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script, permissions, chown

I have shell (`php`) script that gets in touch with target file this way:

- inspects whether file and directory are writable with `php` 's `is_writable()` (I don't think that this is problem)
- does in-place file edit with `sed` command:

`grep -q "$search" "$passwd_file" && { sed -i "s|$search|$replace|" "$passwd_file"; printf "Password changed!\n"; } || printf "Password not changed!\n"`

As a result I get (everything else correct but) file which was `myuser:www-data` to be `myuser:myuser` .

Does `sed` changes file group ownership as it seems, and how do I avoid it, if possible?

Comment: See also [sed - How is the inplace modification of a file being done?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/146052)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is a little problem with `sed`'s inplace editing mode `-i`. `sed` creates a temporary file in the same directory called `sedy08qMA`, where `y08qMA` is a randomly generated string. That file is filled with the modified contents of the original file. After the operation, `sed` removes the original file and renames the temporary file with the original filename. So it's not a true *inplace edit*. It creates a new file with permissions of the calling user and a new inode number. That behavior is mostly not bad, but for instance, hard links get broken.

However, if you want *true* inplace editing, you should use `ed`. It reads commands from the stdin and edits the file directly, without a temporary file (it's done over `ed`'s memory buffer). A common practise is to use `printf` to generate the command list:

```
printf "%s\n" '1,$s/search/replace/g' wq | ed -s file
```

---

The `printf` command produces output as follows:

```
1,$s/search/replace/g
wq
```

Those two lines are `ed` commands. The first one searches for the string `search` and replaces it with `replace`. The second one writes (`w`) the changes to the file and quits (`q`). `-s` suppresses diagnostic output.

Comment: In case you want to delete lines without changing inode, `printf '1,10d\nw\nq\n' | ed -s file`

Comment: "`sed` removes the original file and renames the temporary file with the original filename" – This suggests there is a time window when no file exists under the original filename. I think this is not what happens. `sed` moves the new file to the old name. There may be a window when the new content exists under both names, but [the old filename leads to the old or to the new content at any given time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22823144/10765659).

Answer (score 9):

The `-i` parameter of `sed` works by creating a temp file during operation, then overwrite the actual file with the temp file in the end.  That's the most likely the cause of the problem, since when creating the temp file ownership defaults to `myuser:myuser`

You can set the `setgid` bit on the parent directory(only if the parent directory is owned by group `www-data`), so that files created under this directory inherit the same group.
to do that:

```
chmod g+s parent-dir-of-your-file
```

I think this is a very typical use of the `setgid` bit.

Comment: @cuonglm I just did a strace on `sed -i`, found the following line in the trace, does it mean it created the temp file in current dir? `open("./sedKyG9Ei", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_EXCL, 0600) = 4`

Comment: @DavidDai: Yes, my mis-memory.

Answer (score 3):

The use of `ed` instead of `sed` seems rather superfluous for this, given you have to pipe in an additional input. The distro I'm working on right now (CentOS 5.10) has the `-c` option for `sed` that utilizes 'copying' of the temp file rather than simply renaming it when used with the `-i` option. I've tested it and it worked perfectly, preserving the original owner and group when doing an inline edit. It does NOT preserve the modification time.

e.g., `sed -ci -e '3,5d' file.txt`

- `-c` uses copy instead of rename (i.e., preserves ownership/group)
- `-i` inline editing
- `-e` script/expression to be executed

Not sure how widespread this option is for `sed` across other distros. Solaris 10 didn't have it, but Solaris doesn't have a lot of things I want.

Comment: Sounds pretty handy. Not in Ubuntu 14.04 though, FWIW. :-(

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue when modifying a config file that was being watched by an application. If I edited the file with `sed -i`, the original file would get deleted and the watch would break.

A workaround to this is to use `sed` without `-i` and pipe it to a new file, then overwrite the old file with the new file like.

Example:

```
➜ ls -i config.cson
16777299 config.cson

➜ sed -r 's/"[^"]+-ui"/"vibrant-dark-ui"/' config.cson > config.cson.modified

➜ cat config.cson.modified > config.cson

➜ rm config.cson.modified

➜ ls -i config.cson
16777299 config.cson
```

It's an annoying workaround, but at least it works! The inode of the original file did not change.